# PHP: Convert while loop in array

Tags: php, arrays

How to convert below result into array? I want to make an array so I can assign to variable and use it

```
if($handle = opendir($path)){
    while(false != ($filename = readdir($handle))) {
        if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
            $name = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $filename);
            $name = str_replace('_', ' ', $name);
            $name = ucwords($name);
                echo $name;
        }           
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: so what's your question? how to insert an item into an array? because then all the code you posted is just noise..

Comment: Oh! new to php :( for instance in WP theme option where I have to use variable to assign select option value. since that's an array to crate field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the names to an array....

```
$files = array();
if($handle = opendir($path)){
    while(false != ($filename = readdir($handle))) {
        if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
            $name = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $filename);
            $name = str_replace('_', ' ', $name);
            $name = ucwords($name);
            $files[] = $name;
        }           
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Yes.. I tried but it wan't allowing me now selected..